# Create new datacolumn in datatable C# and populate its rows as serial number based on other column in same datatable

Tags: c#, datatables

I want to create new datacolumn in datatable C# and populate its rows as serial number based on other column in same datatable.

For eg, below is my datatable structure
| ID   | SomeCol | SomeOth |
|:---- |:-------:| -------:|
| 456  | abc     | def     |
| 500  | ghi     | jkl     |
| 505  | mno     | pqr     |

In this datatable, I want to add column Srno and based on ID asc field, generate sequence no as 1,2,3 etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want this ? - Maybe there is a better way to achieve your final goal. Show us your code - what did you already try ?

Comment: @AndrewR I want to divide the datatable into equal batches in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

```
   DataTable dt = new DataTable("Testtable");
            DataColumn[] dtcol = { new DataColumn ("Sid") { AutoIncrement = true , AutoIncrementStep =1 , AutoIncrementSeed =1},
               new DataColumn("SName"),
               new DataColumn("Surl"),  };

            dt.Columns.AddRange(dtcol);
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["SName"] = "Google";
            dr["Surl"] = "www.google.com";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            dr = dt.NewRow();

            dr["SName"] = "Bing";
            dr["Surl"] = "www.bing.com";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            dr = dt.NewRow();

            dr["SName"] = "Yahoo";
            dr["Surl"] = "www.yahoo.com";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```